# Python, Input doesnt set variable

Tags: python, variables, input

Im new to python, and im truly confused, please help

```py
boole = False
alpha = input()
int(alpha)
if alpha == 2:
    boole = True

print(boole)
```

it outputs False, when I want it to output true

Comment: did you mean to do alpha=int(alpha) ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `int(alpha)` isn't doing anything. You need to assign it to a variable. Or rather, a cleaner approach is to wrap the input() call with it.

```
alpha = int(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not saving the `int(alpha)` in `alpha`, so the variable is still holding the value of the input as a String value.

change that line:

```
alpha = int(alpha)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call input() first and imagine that it is the thing user inputted.
Then make the input an integer by using this:
`alpha = int(input())`